# Random sample for create a new dataframe, using loop or other alternative

Tags: r, database, function, loops, data.table

I have three dataframes with different number of rows and I would like to create a new dataframe with random 100 values from these dataframes and based on two criteria:

a - Column a and b in 100 random values

b - The first 50 rows of columns c and d in 50 paired values, that
occur in the same row from dataframe 2 (c1 and d1)

c - The subsequent 50 rows of columns (51-100) c and d in 50 paired values, that occur in the same row from dataframe 3 (c2 and d2)

I tried to loop but it's not bad. How could I do this better? Thanks

Here are the data and script, and the expected result:

```
a <- c(4,6,7,3,2,5,6,9,6,5,8,6,7,8,9,7,6)
b <- c(40,60,70,30,20,NA,60,90,60,50,75,34,42,32,NA,45,29)

c1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
d1 <- c(10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)

c2 <- c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
d2 <- c(20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11)

df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df2 <- data.frame(c1,d1)
df3 <- data.frame(c2,d2)

#newdf (with 100 rows)

n <- 100
newdf <- data.frame(n=rep(1:n))
newdf$a <- NA 
newdf$b <- NA 
newdf$c <- NA
newdf$d<- NA

for (i in 1:50){
  newdf$a[i] <- sample(df1$a, 1, replace=T) # random value
  newdf$b[i] <- sample(df1$b, 1, replace=T) # random value 
  newdf$c[i] <- sample[df2$c1,1, replace=T] # one criterion
  newdf$d[i] <- sample[df2$d1,1, replace=T] # one criterion
}

for (i in 51:100){
  newdf$a[i] <- sample(df1$a, 1, replace=T) # random value
  newdf$b[i] <- sample(df1$b, 1, replace=T) # random value 
  newdf$c[i] <- sample[df3$c2,1, replace=T] # two criterion
  newdf$d[i] <- sample[df3$d2,1, replace=T] #two criterion
}

#Result 

a     b      c    d
7     60     1    10 # one row
6     50     3    8
2     90     5    6  # fifth row
.
.
.
2     90     11    20  # fifth-one row
.
.
.
```

Comment: You may be able to use package `dplyr` with code something like
`df1 %>% sample_n(100) %>% inner_join (df2[1:50,], by=c("x1" = "y1",  "x2 = "y2")` where the x1,x2,y1,y2 are actual column names

Comment: Hi, @epi99 . Thanks for the contribution. I used dply and this error appears: 'c1' column not found in lhs, cannot join. `newdf <- df1 %>% sample_n((100), replace=TRUE) %>% inner_join (df2[1:50,], by=c("c1" = "c", "d1" = "d"))`
Is that correct?

Comment: You have no columns named 'c' or 'd'. When joining from df1 to df2 then the df1 columns should be on the left -- so something like `by=c("a" = "c1", "b" = "d1")`. when I look at your sample data, though there are no matches between the pairs of df1 and df2. Also, you probably don't want `replace=TRUE` -- with smaller datasets use much smaller values of n

Comment: Yes, I have columns c and d in the new dataframe that just would like to create it. I would like to merge sample data from d1 + df2 and df3. A and B are random values. C1 and D1 that I would like to match.

Comment: Is the match based on values in data frames -- or based on the row number? My previous examples would be for matching on values. IF it is by row number something like

`library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  sample_n(5) %>%
  merge(df2, by=0)`

The `by=0 `indicates to merge by row names.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot follow your expected results exactly. Example there is no pair (a,b) = (7, 60). Hopefully below is close to what you need

```
set.seed = 123
library(dplyr)
# use a shorter set, because it needs to match by row number
df1_short <- df1[1:10,]

# take the sample (using 6 here because it is less than the 10 we ahve)
df1_sampled <- df1_short %>% sample_n(6) 

# build the two halves separately, merge by row numbers (by=0)
df1a <- df1_sampled[1:3,] %>% merge(df2, by=0) %>% rename(c = c1, d = d1)
df1b <- df1_sampled[4:6,] %>% merge(df3, by=0) %>% rename(c = c2, d = d2)

# combine the two sets
result <- bind_rows(df1a, df1b) 
result

#   Row.names a  b  c  d
# 1         1 4 40  1 10
# 2         7 6 60  7  4
# 3         9 6 60  9  2
# 4        10 5 50 20 11
# 5         2 6 60 12 19
# 6         3 7 70 13 18
```